# Devise 2.2 + Google OAuth2 undefined method `serialize_into_session'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, oauth-2.0

I got Devise setup and working for my app. When i add

`gem omniauth-google-oauth2`

im getting an error in controller `sign_in_and_redirect` method.

**Error:**

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `serialize_into_session' for String:Class):
  app/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb:9:in `google_oauth2'
```

**Code:**

omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb

```
def google_oauth2
    @user = User.find_for_google_oauth2(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)
    if @user.persisted?
      flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.success", :kind => "Google"
      sign_in_and_redirect sites_path, :event => :authentication
    else
      session["devise.google_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
end
```

user.rb

```
def self.find_for_google_oauth2(access_token, signed_in_resource=nil)
    data = access_token.info
    user = User.where(:email => data["email"]).first

    unless user
      user = User.create(email: data["email"],
                         password: Devise.friendly_token[0, 20]
      )
    end
    user
end
```

devise.rb

```
require "omniauth-google-oauth2"
config.omniauth :google_oauth2, 'CLIENT_ID', 'CLIENT_SECRET', {access_type: "offline", approval_prompt: ""}
```

Please let me know if im missing something.

Comment: Its a incorrect function call that was causing the issue. I changed the sign_in_and_redirect sites_path, :event => :authentication to sign_in_and_redirect(:user, @user) and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your config is good, but I use for this situation instead `omniauth-google-oauth2`, this gem https://rubygems.org/gems/omniauth-openid.

Add to your `/config/initializer/devise.rb` the next:

```
require 'openid/store/filesystem'
config.omniauth :open_id, :store => OpenID::Store::Filesystem.new('/tmp'), :name => 'google', :identifier => 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id', :require => 'omniauth-openid'
```

and after inside your `omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb` change the method `User.find_for_google_oauth2...` by `User.find_for_open_id...`

on your `user` model change the `self.find_for_google_oauth2` by `self.find_for_open_id`.

**Try with this gem please!**

Comment: Thanks. But the problem is openid is no more in use and even Google prefers to use OAuth2.